# Mathematical operation with XML node values for selection

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to use the value of an XML node to select a group of nodes, my specific problem is the following.
I have the nodes computers with the attribute model and in their children is the node HardDrive

```
<PC model="Lindows OSX">
    <HardDrive>500</HardDrive>
</PC>
```

I'd like to select only the PCs which HardDrive is over 500gb, so I dont know if the function text() let's me work with numbers, something like

```
//parent::HardDrive[text()>500]/@model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[text()>500]` is a valid XPath condition.
That's what you want I reckon:

```
//PC[HardDrive > 500]/@model
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, this one looks definitely better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following XPath:

```
root/PC[HardDrive[. > 500]]/@model
```

It will extract all model names of PCs with hard drive capacity > 500.

Demo at [xpathtester.com](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/dd7ef1b279fe7c7a7d07fe2a6d31f243).